Group by, count distinct SQL query to IQueryable using Linq
I am trying to translate the following SQL into IQueryable, so I can access the result and filter on different conditions, before the data is retrieved from the database,
but I get an error that the LINQ query can't be translated.
 SELECT
    a.Id AS HandymanId,
    u.SubscriptionSource,
    a.TrialExpiryDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.Id) AS PhoneCallCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.RecordingSid IS NOT NULL AND b.RecordingSid <> '' THEN b.Id END) AS VoiceMessageCount,  
    COUNT(DISTINCT d.Id) AS AppointmentCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e.Id) AS TodoCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.Id) AS DocumentationCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT g.Id) AS MessageCount
FROM
    [dbo].[Handymen] a
LEFT JOIN
    PhoneCalls b ON a.Id = b.HandymanId
LEFT JOIN
    [Identity].[User] u ON u.Id = a.ApplicationUserId
LEFT JOIN
    Projects c ON a.Id = c.HandymanId
LEFT JOIN
    Appointments d ON c.Id = d.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN
    Todos e ON e.ProjectId = c.Id
LEFT JOIN
    Documentations f ON f.ProjectId = c.Id
LEFT JOIN
    [Messages] g ON g.ProjectId = c.Id
GROUP BY
    a.Id, u.SubscriptionSource, a.TrialExpiryDate;

from user in context.Handymen
               join call in context.PhoneCalls on user.Id equals call.HandymanId into callGroup
               join appointment in context.Appointments on user.Id equals appointment.Project.HandymanId into appointmentGroup
               join todo in context.Todos on user.Id equals todo.Project.HandymanId into todoGroup
               join documentation in context.Documentations on user.Id equals documentation.Project.HandymanId into documentationGroup
               join enquiry in context.Projects on user.Id equals enquiry.HandymanId into enquiryGroup
               join message in context.Messages on user.Id equals message.Project.HandymanId into messageGroup
               where user.HandymanProTrialExpiryDate > DateTime.UtcNow
               select new MyData
                   {
                       Id = user.Id,                       
                       CallCount = callGroup.Select(call => call.Id).Distinct().Count(),
                       AppointmentCount = appointmentGroup.Select(appointment => appointment.Id).Distinct().Count(),
                       TodoCount = todoGroup.Select(todo => todo.Id).Distinct().Count(),
                       DocumentationCount = documentationGroup.Select(documentation => documentation.Id).Distinct().Count(),
                       EnquiryCount = enquiryGroup.Select(enquiry => enquiry.Id).Distinct().Count(),
                       MessageCount = messageGroup.Select(message => message.Id).Distinct().Count()
                   }


b.RecordingSid != null doesn't do what you think it does. The correct way to write this is b.RecordingSid NOT IS NULL

Maybe it's not the correct way of doing it, but the SQL returns the expected results

I doubt this query actually works correctly. You are using a large number of one to many joins, and the distincting over that, which isn't necessarily correct. You need to pre-aggregate the joins by HandymanId first.

The query returns the expected results and my question is not towards the sql, but towards translating the SQL to LINQ

I would add that I don't really care about how the LINQ is translated to SQL (so it doesn't have to be a group by distint), so long it is queryable and gives the same result and don't need to be loaded into memory first. @Charlieface I think, if I get you right, what you said is actually being done already, I only renamed a.Id to HandymanId in the select so it is more clear in the result, but the group by is effectively by HandymanId

Which EF Core version do you use?

Whether or not the LINQ can be translated, I don't think the original query is even correct.
So rather than joining everything and aggregating afterwards, you need to pre-aggregate the joins, and not use COUNT(DISTINCT.
from user in context.Handymen
where user.HandymanProTrialExpiryDate > DateTime.UtcNow
let calls = context.PhoneCalls
    .Where(call => user.Id == call.HandymanId)
    .GroupBy(call => 0)  // group by empty set
    .Select(g => new { CallCount = g.Count(), VoiceMessageCount = g.Count(c => c.RecordingSid != "") })
select new MyData
{
    Id = user.Id,
    calls.CallCount,
    calls.VoiceMessageCount,
    AppointmentCount = context.Appointments.Where(app => user.Id == app.Project.HandymanId).Count(),
    TodoCount = context.Todos(todo => user.Id == todo.Project.HandymanId).Count(),
    DocumentationCount = context.Documentations.Where(doc => user.Id == doc.Project.HandymanId).Count(),
    MessageCount = context.Messages.Where(msg => user.Id == msg.Project.HandymanId).Count()
}

Ideally you would be able to use navigation properties:
from user in context.Handymen
where user.HandymanProTrialExpiryDate > DateTime.UtcNow
let calls = user.PhoneCalls
    .GroupBy(call => 0)  // group by empty set
    .Select(g => new { CallCount = g.Count(), VoiceMessageCount = g.Count(c => c.RecordingSid != "") })
select new MyData
{
    Id = user.Id,
    calls.CallCount,
    calls.VoiceMessageCount,
    AppointmentCount = user.Projects.SelectMany(p => p.Appointments).Count(),
    TodoCount = user.Projects.SelectMany(p => p.Todos).Count(),
    DocumentationCount = user.Projects.SelectMany(p => p.Documentations).Count(),
    MessageCount = user.Projects.SelectMany(p => p.Messages).Count()
}

You can even pre-aggregate Projects, which might be more efficient
from user in context.Handymen
where user.HandymanProTrialExpiryDate > DateTime.UtcNow
let calls = user.PhoneCalls
    .GroupBy(call => 0)  // group by empty set
    .Select(g => new { CallCount = g.Count(), VoiceMessageCount = g.Count(c => c.RecordingSid != "") })
let projects = user.Projects
    .Select(p => new
    {
        AppointmentCount = p.Appointments.Count(),
        TodoCount = p.Todos.Count(),
        DocumentationCount = p.Documentations.Count(),
        MessageCount = p.Messages.Count()
    })
    .GroupBy(p => 0)  // group by empty set
    .Select(g => new
    {
        AppointmentCount = g.Sum(p => p.AppointmentCount),
        TodoCount = g.Sum(p => p.TodoCount),
        DocumentationCount = g.Sum(p => p.DocumentationCount),
        MessageCount = g.Sum(p => p.MessageCount)
    })
select new MyData
{
    Id = user.Id,
    calls.CallCount,
    calls.VoiceMessageCount,
    projects.AppointmentCount,
    projects.TodoCount,
    projects.DocumentationCount,
    projects.MessageCount,
}


EF Core 7, should support COUNT(DISTINCT ..) via g.Select(x => x.Field).Distinct().Count()

@SvyatoslavDanyliv That may be, but it's not the correct approach anyway, as mentioned.
